# How to do something after element's resized

Tags: jquery

I have div#myid that is resizeable with minHeight = 30px;

I want to do something to another div div#myotherid, e.g. adding new class..

Have do trying the following, but no luck..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ( $( "#myid" ).css( "height" ) == "30px" ) {
    $( "#myotherid" ).addClass( "newclass" );
    }
```

});

So, what is the other way to do??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at http://docs.jquery.com/Events/resize.